# Ruby FileUtils: copying file

Tags: ruby, windows

Hello I try to copy file with help of `FileUtils`

```
file_path = "C:/example/abc.txt"
destination_directory = "C:/destination"

FileUtils.cp(file_path, destination_directory)
```

When I try run this code there is an error `can't convert Fixnum into String`.
Where did I make a mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use backslashes for windows paths, then escape them to make them literal i.e.

```
file_path = "C:\\example\\abc.txt"
destination_folder = "C:\\destination"

FileUtils.cp(file_path, destination_folder)
```

**EDIT**

As Tin Man pointed out, this is incorrect: it works but it is **not necessary** in any way.

I guess that it should work as it is; could it might just be a typo? As toro2k pointed out, you wrote `destination_folder` first and then `destination_directory`

Comment: I think you should check your code, where `destination_directory` comes from?

Comment: You do *NOT* have to use backslashes for Windows paths. Read the [IO documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html): `Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb".`

Comment: Actually windows also supports "/" as pathname separator where usage is unambiguous with command parameters. So actually problem occurs only if command line parsing is involved.